# Why does from pkg import * end up importing a module even if __all__ is not defined?

Tags: python, package, python-import, python-3.6

I have created a package `pkg` in this manner.

```
$ tree
.
└── pkg
    ├── foo.py
    └── __init__.py

1 directory, 2 files
susam@debian1:~/so$ cat pkg/__init__.py
susam@debian1:~/so$ cat pkg/foo.py
print('executing module foo ...')

def bar():
    print('bar')
```

All the Python shell snippets below are from a single interactive
session with the Python interpreter. I have split them up into multiple
blocks to add my own commentary in between.

Here is my Python version.

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

The following import does not import `foo` because `__all__` is not
defined in `__init__.py`.

```
>>> from pkg import *
>>> foo.bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
>>>
```

The above behaviour has been described in the Python tutorial at
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package.

> If `__all__` is not defined, the statement `from sound.effects import *`
>   does not import all submodules from the package `sound.effects` into the
>   current namespace; it only ensures that the package `sound.effects` has
>   been imported (possibly running any initialization code in
>   `__init__.py`) and then imports whatever names are defined in the
>   package.

The following imports only `bar()`. It does not import `foo`.

```
>>> from pkg.foo import bar
executing module foo ...
>>> bar()
bar
>>> foo.bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

But strangely after the previous import, the following import ends up
importing `foo` even if `__all__` is not defined in `__init__.py`.

```
>>> from pkg import *
>>> foo.bar()
bar
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the Python documentation that you cited, when you use `from pkg import *` you are importing only the module `foo` as well as `__init__.py` and not the functions of `foo`.

I suspect the last code snippet you provided works because you have already imported `bar()` directly from `foo` and reimporting `foo` after you've strictly imported the bar function establishes the connection between `foo` and `bar()`.

Do you run into this same issue when specifying `__all__`?

Comment: `from pkg import *` should not import the module `foo` unless `__all__` is defined. I don't run into the same issue if `__all__` is specified. What I am curious to understand is why the first occurrence of `from pkg import *` agrees with the documentation, i.e. does not import `foo` but the second occurrence of `from pkg import *` violates the documentation and imports `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

`foo` is already imported in `pkg` namespace as `pkg.foo` when you do `from pkg.foo import bar`. So when you then import all names from `pkg` namespace to current scope you also import `foo`. See:

```
>>> import pkg
>>> dir(pkg)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
>>> from pkg.foo import bar
executing module foo ...
>>> dir(pkg)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'foo']
```

(I am on python 2 but the logic for this is the same)